# Which identifier am I supposed to use to close my library in R7RS/Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs, r7rs

I'm trying to write a R7RS library which will reverse a list in a destructive manner,

I currently have written this code;

```
#lang r7rs


(define-library (in-place-reverse!)
  (export reverse!)
  (import (scheme base))

(ignore the code below)
;    (define (reverse! list)
;      (if (null? list)
;          '()
;          (append (reverse (cdr list))
;                  (list (car list)))))))
(begin
  
    (define (reverse! lst)
      (define (reverse-hulp! prev cur)
        (cond
          ((null? cur) prev)
          ((next) cdr cur)
          ((set-cdr! cur prev))
          (else
            (reverse-hulp! cur next))))))
              
      (reverse! '() lst))
```

The only thing I'm worried about is the error i'm receiving.

```
 define-library: expected one of these identifiers: `import', `export', `begin', `cond-expand', or `include'
  parsing context: 
   while parsing library clause in: reverse!
```

Is my code even working as i'm asking it to? any kind of advice is appreciated!

Tried to implement a reverse procedure as I would in R5RS only this time i'm using destructive operators.

Comment: `(reverse! '() lst)` isn't one of the expected forms in a `define-library` expression...

Comment: Plus it uses two arguments and your function only takes one.

Comment: @shawn I tried writing this in an iterative way, I'm fairly new to writing in Scheme, let alone libraries, so any kind of feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You can't have top level expressions like that in a library definition

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to get your function working outside a library first.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message doesn't match your code.
When I run your example I get the error:

```
define-library: expected one of these identifiers: `import', `export', `begin', `cond-expand', or `include'
  parsing context: 
   while parsing library clause in: ignore
```

If I comment out the `ignore` form, I get your error and the expression `(reverse! '() lst)` is highlighted.

The problem is that the expression is outside the `begin`.
Also, the intention was probably to make start the process in `reverse!`.

```
#lang r7rs


(define-library (in-place-reverse!)
  (export reverse!)
  (import (scheme base))

  (begin
  
    (define (reverse! lst)
      (define (reverse-hulp! prev cur)
        (cond
          ((null? cur) prev)
          ((next) cdr cur)
          ((set-cdr! cur prev))
          (else
           (reverse-hulp! cur next))))
      (reverse! '() lst))))
```

Then you need to figure out what to do about `next`.